# Rewrite htaccess rules not working perfect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a bunch of rules for different categories, here is one category...

```
RewriteRule ^words/$ /words/publicWordLists.php [L]
RewriteRule ^words/([A-Za-z]+$) /words/word.php?word=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/words/$ /words/userWordLists.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/words/([A-Za-z0-9-]+$) /words/list.php?username=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

This works great in that if you go to words/ you get the content from publicWordsList.php - HOWEVER - if you go to directly to /words/publicWordLists.php - it doesn't redirect back to words/

So how do I prevent people from directly accessing those pages while still maintaining my initial intentions?

Comment: Create a function and redirect to the proper version of URLs: https://www.tinywebhut.com/remove-duplicate-urls-from-your-website-38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "redirect" at the top of the file that 301 redirects from the "ugly" filesystem path to the desired URL. However, you need to be careful of redirect loops, since the later *rewrite* rewrites the URL back again.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^words/publicWordLists\.php$ /words/ [R=302,L]
```

The check against the environment variable `REDIRECT_STATUS` prevents a redirect loop as it only looks at the initial request, not the rewritten request. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty initially, but set to "200" after the first successful rewrite.

Change `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only once you have confirmed everything works OK - to avoid potential caching issues.

Your other directives that contain a query string are a little more tricky as they require an additional condition. The *query string* is not part of the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^word=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^words/word\.php$ /words/%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The above redirects `/word/word.php?word=<something>` to `/words/<something>`.

`%1` is a backreference to the URL parameter value captured in the preceding `RewriteCond` directive. The `QSD` flag is necessary to remove the original query string from the redirected request.

**UPDATE:** The `QSD` flag is Apache 2.4+. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then instead you an append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string (essentially an empty query string) in order to remove the query string from the redirected URL. For example, on **Apache 2.2** you would need this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^words/word\.php$ /words/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: This ALMOST works perfectly so far, I really appreciate your expert help. The first one works exactly as described. But in the redirect with the query string, the QSD is causing the entire site to get internal service errors. If I take the QSD out, it does as you suggested (redirects properly, but does not remove the query string). Thoughts?

Comment: What version of Apache are you on? The `QSD` flag is Apache 2.4+. On Apache 2.2 you will need to append an empty query string instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You're right, I am on apache 2.2. Awesome help, thanks again!